# Having problems with this integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm currently working on a problem in Electrodynamics and by trying to calculate the correct Electric field I arrived at the following integral:
$$\int_0^L\frac{\sqrt{x'}}{(x-x')^2}dx'$$

I've tried to solve it for quite some time now by trying substitution or expanding out the denominator but I can't seem to get it right. Plugging it into an online calculator (Wolfram Alpha for example) sadly also doesn't get me any further.

It would be really awesome if anyone knew how to approach such an integral and could give me a hint on how to calculate it.

It could also be the case that the integral itself is wrong but I'm quite sure that it should be correct (Unless you say that it is not solvable, then I have to rethink the calculations).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Making the substitution $$t=\sqrt{x'},$$
the integral becomes $$2\int_0^{\sqrt{L}}\frac{t^2dt}{(x-t^2)^2}$$

which can be computed by partial fractions.

Comment: Worth nothing that the standard integral $\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}\, dx=\arctan(x)+c$ is involved.

Answer (score 1):

WA gives you the indefinite integral, which is all you need:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%28t%29%2F%28a-t%29%5E2+

Comment: Thanks for that! I sadly just tried it with the definite integral. Is there a reason why WolframAlpha or some ohter calculation program is not able to compute the definite integral here?

Comment: @markus: Wolfram clamps Alpha so that it does not have all capabilities of Mathematica. But here it does not matter at all.